# Why is callback function executing in the component I pass it to when its rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

### Question

I'm encountering a React warning: `Cannot update a component (LabourTriggerProvider) while rendering a different component (CrudTableProvider)`. The structure of my application involves multiple contexts and the use of callbacks for CRUD operations in a table component. However, I'm facing this warning even though the callbacks are seemingly executed only in response to user interactions like button clicks or form submissions.
Relevant Code:

#### LabourTriggerProvider (Context Provider):

```js
export const LabourTriggerProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [labourTrigger, setLabourTrigger] = useState(false);
  const toggleLabourTrigger = () => {
    setLabourTrigger(prev => !prev);
  };
  return (
    <LabourContext.Provider value={{ labourTrigger, toggleLabourTrigger }}>
      {children}
    </LabourContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

#### CrudTableProvider (Context Provider):

```js
export const CrudTableProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [submitCb, setSubmitCb] = useState(() => newitem => {});
  // ... other state and setters
  return (
    <CrudTableContext.Provider value={{ submitCb, setSubmitCb, ... }}>
      {children}
    </CrudTableContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

#### LabourTable Component:

```js
const LabourTable = ({ projectID }) => {
  const { setSubmitCb } = useCrudTable();
  const { toggleLabourTrigger } = useLabourTrigger();

  const submitCb = (labourLineItem) => {
    // Callback logic...
    toggleLabourTrigger();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setSubmitCb(submitCb);
  }, [submitCb]);

  // ... LabourTable component logic
};
```

#### CrudTable Component:

```js
    const CrudTable = ({ table, itemFields, ... }) => {
      const { submitCb } = useCrudTable();
      const { itemList, setItemList, submitCb, updateCb, deleteCb, where } = useCrudTable();

      const submitHandler = (newItem) => {
        submitCb(newItem);
        // ... CRUD operation logic
      };

      // ... CrudTable component logic

     return (
    <>
      // ... Other Components
      <GenericForm initialState={initialState} onSubmit={submitHandler} fields={itemFields} />
    </>
  )
    };
```

### GenericForm Component:

```js
const GenericForm = ({ initialState, onSubmit, fields }) => {
  const [item, setItem] = useState(initialState)

  // ... GenericForm operation logic

  // Handles form submission
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setSubmitTrigger(prev => !prev)
    onSubmit(item)
    setItem(initialState)
  }

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
```

There are other components and functions not included here for sack of brevity notably an updateCb, a deleteCb, and a GenericItem component but they are handled in the same manner. Originally the application did not use context in this situation and the logic worked as intended, however I had to add the context due to need for a components to have access to CrudTable's itemList and setItemList.

#### Question:

Could there be a nuanced issue related to context, state updates, or the execution flow of callbacks causing this warning? How can I resolve this warning given the current structure of my application? What am I not understanding about the inner workings of React?

#### What I've Tried:

- Ensured toggleLabourTrigger is only called within submitCb, which in turn is only triggered by user actions (form submission or button click).
- Checked for unintentional render triggers or state updates during the render phase of any component.
- Verified that toggleLabourTrigger or the callbacks in useCrudTable are not being invoked during the render phase of any component.
- Included `console.log()` calls to identify where `toggleLabourTigger` is being executed. It is being executed in 2 sets of 2 when CrudTable is rendering.
- Many Many Many google searches, I have only come up with information about `useCallback` which seemingly is a good idea for me to implement however I do not think its related to my issue. But i may be wrong I am new to React.
- Simplify my components for debugging to try to identify the issue with no luck.

Despite these checks, the warning persists. The expected behavior is for the toggleLabourTrigger function to be called only in response to user actions and not during the rendering or initialization phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suspect your issue is with this code from LabourTable:

```js
const submitCb = (labourLineItem) => {
  // Callback logic...
  toggleLabourTrigger();
};

useEffect(() => {
  setSubmitCb(submitCb);
}, [submitCb]);
```

Every single time LabourTable renders (i.e. every time the LabourTable function is run), it will get a NEW VALUE for `submitCb` because the function will be created each and every time.  So the `useEffect()` will run each and every time, sending a NEW VALUE (a new compile of the `submitCb` function) to `setSubmitCb()`, which will in turn cause CrudTableProvider to be scheduled to re-render....but CrudTableProvider is already rendering...that is what caused LabourTable to render in the first place.  Thus....circular renderings -- infinite loop!  Thankfully React caught the problem and let you know about it.

The solution would be to avoid such circular rendering.  You could use `useCallback()` for the value of `submitCb` such that it only gets generated once and is cached and re-used across future renders.  But you really want to understand the cycle of dependencies you are setting up in your code.

React is a super simple system in the grand scheme of things (it is the asynchronous behaviour of JavaScript that makes things seem quite complicated).

- A React COMPONENT is just a JS function
- A React component expects just one argument: an object that we lovingly call PROPS
- When a React component RENDERS, that is just the function executing like any other JS function
- A component will render in only 2 cases:

  - its parent renders
  - a state variable (`useState()`) in the component is given a new value via the "set state function"
- HOOKS are the name of a function that will throw an error if they are invoked (called) by anything other than a React component or another React hook
- the useState hook creates a STATE VARIABLE and its SET STATE FUNCTION

  - state variables are recreated each render, but are given the ending value from the previous render (this gives the *illusion* that state variables are persistent)
  - the set state function is asynchronous; when run it updates the value in its associated state variable and schedules the component to be re-rendered
- useEffect, useCallback, useMemo (and other hooks) are provided a CALLBACK function and have ***dependencies***, typically state variables but can be other values such as a value in the props. These hooks will only run their callback function if any of their dependencies have a newer value during the current render of its component than the previous render [note: they will run the callback on first render of their component]

What I am suggesting above is that you want to ensure that the state variables in parent components are not modified by their descendent (child) components when the child component is rendering because of the parent component.  Otherwise you end up with:

```
Parent Renders 
  >> Child Renders & updates Parent state
    >> Parent Renders
       >> Child Renders & updates Parent state
          >> Parent Renders
             >> ............
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I came to the realize that my hierarchy of components was not going to work, and therefore context was not the right solution in my case. Your answer gave me the knowledge to come to that realization

Comment: Context can usually be made to work, but sometimes you have to shift the thinking a bit.  I make frequent use of Context (if by "context" you mean the Context API?)